# iphone table server output with cell title and subtitle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I currently have an app which reads a line from a webpage which looks like:

```
1/2/3/4/5/
```

And then it outputs each number in a table in five cells.

However, I would like to output some extra info along with the numbers, so that my table cells have a title and a subtile.

```
Title: 1
Subtitle: Number one
Title: 2
Subtile: Number two

etc.
```

But I don't quite know where to store the subtitle text - do I need to read a new line from the webpage, or is it possible to store both title and subtitle in the same line, like say:

```
1, Number one/2, Number two/3, Number three/
```

And then tell the app to use the first item as title and the second as subtitle?

Comment: u can write a function that takes the number say 1 as input and output "Number one" ie by conditions, as output .this function would give the text for subtitle (only if numbers are between 0-9 :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, when you create a new cell, define the detailText of that cell as `Subtitle: Number one` and also make changes to the **cell Style** as below:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Whenever you create a cell for **Title:1** you just need to define the `detailText.text` property for the cell value. If `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` this does not works then try using different style of the `UITableViewCell`.